# Как найти элемент по значению + проблема со стилями в IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте всем! Передо мной возникла такая задача:

1) Дано:

```
<select id="selectId">

<option value="value1" selected="selected">value1</option>
<option value="value1" style="display:none;">value2</option>
<option value="value1" style="display:none;">value3</option>

</select>
```

Найти: функцию js, которая бы вбирала один `<option>` по его значению и меняла его стиль. Присваивать name либо id опциям нельзя.

2) `style="display:none;"` для тега `<option>` не пашет в IE и Opera. Не имею даже малейшей идеи почему...

Буду признательна любым предложениям =)

Answer (score 3):

display:none у option не работает вообще нигде, кроме фф. Для chrome можно сделать visibility:hidden, но место останется. Можно использовать line-height, но в ие все равно элемент будет виден.

Если jQuery, то написал [@metazet](/users/254/metazet)

Если js чистый, то:

```
var opts = document.getElementById('selectId').getElementsByTagName('option');
for (var i in opts) {
    if (opts[i].getAttribute('value') == 'value1') {
        opts[i].style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. селектор на jQuery: $("#selectId option[value='value1']").css("style", "some: some;"); либо добавление класса через $("selector").addClass("class_name");
2. попробуте !important, хотя тут я хз если честно...

Answer (score 0):

2) Как вариант, можно написать js класс, который бы составлял список option'ов, удалял option из select'а и возвращал обратно option из списка.
Также можно стилизовать select с помощью jquery плагина. Тогда select заменится на другой тег (ul, если не ошибаюсь), а с ним работать уже проще.